# What is a word for overconsumption with the goal of getting your money's worth?

Tags: single-word-requests

A good example would be going to a buffet and overeating, or going to Disney World from sunup to sundown to maximize the experience. The caveat being that you’re no longer possibly enjoying it.

I want to emphasize that the word (or phrase, I suppose) should convey **the pain in pursuing the task**, where the task would normally be enjoyable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133032/discussion-on-question-by-karmachamelion-what-is-a-word-for-overconsumption-with).

Answer (score 10):

**milk** / **overmilk**

**milk** (v.)

> Get all possible advantages from a situation  [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/milk)

> Exploit as much as possible [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/milk)

> To draw or coerce profit or advantage from illicitly or to an extreme degree: EXPLOIT
>
> *milk the joke for all it's worth*
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/milk)

**overmilk** (v.)

> to exploit (something) to an excessive degree
>
> *The overall … fall in 2010 could be attributed to greedy promoters overmilking the market.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overmilk)

---

> (Translation: You are at Disneyland with a Park Hopper ticket, but it's
> up to you how many rides you go on before the park closes....*The
> price of your ticket has been paid in full, so I say you **milk** it
> for all it's worth!)* [Levi Lusko; *Swipe Right*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Swipe_Right/8ztvDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Milk%20the%20price%20of%20admission%20for%20all%20its%20worth&pg=PA16&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

> MR. O'NEILL: *And they lost $37 million RFC money, and the house was
> priced at $16,000 when they went under.* MR.BICKET: And the members of
> the corporation **milked** it until it wasn't there any more. [*US
> National Commission on Urban Problems*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hearings/9jxFAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22milked%20it%20until%22%20felt&pg=PA300&printsec=frontcover) (1968)

> Armstrong doesn't **overmilk** it. He's quietly effective as Davis
> would acknowledge: “I'm there to give it my all, because I'm the star,
> and then they show a closeup of Louis and suddenly it turns into a
> Louis Armstrong movie. [Kevin Whitehead; *Play it the Way You
> Feel*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Play_the_Way_You_Feel/CY_UDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22overmilk%22&pg=PA190&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

> There's no doubting this musician's technical arsenal—breathtaking
> passagework, silky diminuendos—but this was an overwrought performance
> with every legato **overmilked** and every plangent phrase drenched in
> anguish. Times, Sunday Times (2008) [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/overmilk)

> "What I hope doesn't happen is that there is a flood of incompetent
> product," Atlantic's Azzoli says. "We have a tendency to kill or
> **overmilk** good ideas in this business." [*Billboard*, June 14, 2003](https://books.google.com/books?id=_g0EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA83&dq=kill%20or%20overmilk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje89Psp6f1AhUSnWoFHYg5Ab0Q6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=kill%20or%20overmilk&f=false)

Comment: Perhaps not the most suitable metaphor for an eating binge. // [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/milk) has a more appropriate definition for overindulgence: 'to an extreme degree : EXPLOIT
milk the joke for all it's worth'.

Comment: I like *milking it*. It has the right overtones of getting all you possibly can from the circumstances, including over-eating, or - more generally - consuming more than you need. It is similar to "getting your money's worth".

Comment: It really doesn't emphasize straining oneself to get the most out of something.

Comment: I've added *overmilk* :-)

Comment: i do still think neither fit the question - "milking" (and by association "overmilking") implies that there's more benefit the longer you do it imo.

Answer (score 3):

Though not a single word as requested, you could try the common phrase:

**Squeezing [all] the <fun/enjoyment/etc.> out of**

> to get or obtain something from someone with difficulty, or to cause something to happen by a continuous and difficult effort

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/squeeze-something-out-of-someone-something)

This implies that there is still something to be obtained from the task, but it comes at great effort, and that the source will be left barren. It does not quite convey that the person continues once there is nothing left, but this could be made clear by combining with additional wording:

**Stubbornly ...**

> in a way that shows you are determined to do what you want and refuse to do anything else

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stubbornly)

For example using these two together:

> My friend stubbornly squeezed the fun out of having a 3-day Disney pass by attending every day from sunrise to sunset.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider **Overkill**.

> [overkill](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/overkill)

Or this idiom

> [go the whole hog](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+the+whole+hog)

Or perhaps this

> [go to town](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+to+town)

{*To do something to excess or in an uninhibited manner.*}

*The kids sure went to town on those cupcakes—there's none left.*

Comment: To "pig out" and be "like pigs to the trough" also have a similar porcine connection.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Berenstain Bears book called, "Too Much Birthday."  We read it with our children when they were little.  For those familiar with the book, you only have to say, "Too Much Buffet" or "Too Much Birthday."

Answer (score 1):

The situation you depict of people getting most for their money reminds me of the psychological concepts of

- satisficers: those who take the first option who satisfy their needs sufficiently
- maximizers: those trying to get the best option even at the expense of vaste amounts of time and energy, and their emotional well-being ([Wikipedia: Maximization, 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximization_%28psychology%29?wprov=sfla1))

Hence, the word you could be looking for is

**maximize**

> The couple slept in the parking lot next to the amusement park to *maximize* returns from their entry ticket

Ps. You could also say they are dullwitted^~^

Answer (score 1):

*Surfeit* has part of the meaning you need, though it doesn't have the connotation of getting your money's worth.

Answer (score 1):

"Gluttony" is the closest single word I can think of. It doesn't necessarily carry with it the connotation of "getting your money's worth"; but it does express the idea of "overdoing it" to an irrational, detrimental and possibly painful extent. It is usually applied to over-eating, so it is very apt for your "buffet" example, but can be extended to other forms of indulgence, as well as used in idiomatic expressions e.g. "glutton for punishment".

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it short and simple: **greed**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make use of **fixate** or **fixation**, perhaps together with **milking** suggested by DjinTonic.

**fixate** (v.)

> (...)
>
> to focus or concentrate one's gaze or attention intently or obsessively

([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fixate))

**fixation** (n.)

> : the act, process, or result of fixing, fixating, or becoming fixated: such as
>
> (...)
>
> **c** : an obsessive or unhealthy preoccupation or attachment

The phrase to describe the behavior might then be

> *They got fixated on milking everything from the tickets*

This doesn't necessarily imply the pain, but strongly suggests the
diminished enjoyment, and that it's unhealthy preoccupation.

A longer sentence might get it clear, though it's really a description and not a single word then:

> *They got so fixated on milking everything from the tickets, they kept going even after all joy was gone*

Answer (score -2):

This can be viewed as an example of the [sunk cost fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost).

Comment: Could you add a definition to your answer?